# Running bash jobs in parallel with predefined order prioritization

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I want to run 3 jobs (A, B, C) on 2 cores of a machine with >2 cores. I know that:

runtime(A)>runtime(C)

runtime(B)>runtime(C)

It is unknown in advance if runtime(A)>runtime(B) or runtime(A)<runtime(B).

What I want to do is:

- launch A on core 1
- launch B on core 2
- after either one is finished, launch C on the one free core

How can this be achieved (in bash, if possible)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This platform is intended for software developers. You forgot to add in your question what you have tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus An attempt is encouraged, but is not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tell **GNU Parallel** it can use 2 cores:

```
parallel -j 2 ::: jobA jobB jobC
```

Note that the jobs will run in the order you specified, but the output may come in a different order. If that is an issue, add `-k` parameter to keep output in order.

Comment: Brilliant, this works and it makes sense for gnu parallel to respect the order. I previously dismissed parallel because I was under the impression that the order of the output is the same as the order of the execution. But, I guess this is the case only when jobs on different threads finish at about the same time.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy in Bash 4.3 (released in 2014) or later:

```
A &
B &
wait -n # wait for any child to finish
C &
wait # for everyone to finish
```

Comment: `sleep 5; echo "A" & sleep 10; echo "B" & wait -n & sleep 5; echo "C" & wait`  runs in 20 seconds, I expected 10.

And A and B are executed sequentially, aren't they?

Comment: `sleep 5;` executes that and then waits, your example is therefore buggy.  Try writing a script or function called `A` and putting `sleep 5` in it then use the code I gave.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Although I am going with the GNU parallel solution (somewhat easier to extend and maintain), yours is a nifty one and I love it!